# Using RxJava 1.1.5 with Spring boot Transaction is not getting rollbacked

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rx-java, spring-transactions

I'm using RxJava 1.1.5 and Spring Boot 1.3.5 for my application.

We have on huge method doing multiple inserts and updates in database in one transaction as below. When any repository method is throwing an DataException (is RuntimeException) then transaction is not getting rollbacked and I'm able to get the records in DB.

`CodeService.java`

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=DataException.class)
   Public Observable<Optional<Boolean>> doProcess(req1,req2,req3,req4){
           return Observable.zip(repository1.insertRecord1(req1.get(),useFallBack),
                                 repository1.insertRecord2(req2.get(),useFallBack),
                                 repository1.getJRecord(req3.getAccountId(),req4.getId(),useFallBack),
                                 repository1.getTaxRate(req3.getAccountId(),useFallBack),
                                 repository1.getCurrencyByCode(req3.getCurrencyCode(), useFallBack),
                                   (record1,record2,jRecord,raxRate, currencyOp)->{
                                       BigDecimal amountWithoutTax = req4.getAmount().divide(raxRate.get(), currencyOp.get().getDecimalPlaces(), BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
                                       Record3 record3= new Record3();
                                       BigDecimal chargeJournalKey = req4.getId();
                                       record3.setKey(record2.get());
                                       record3.setCollectionKey(record1.get());
                                       record3.setAmount(jRecord.get().getAmount().subtract(req4.getAmount()));
                                       record3.setAmount(amountWithoutTax);
                                       return repository1.insertRecord3(record3);
                                   });
                               }
```

`CodeRepository.java`

```
public Observable<Optional<BigDecimal>> insertRecord1(req1.get(),useFallBack){..}

public Observable<Optional<BigDecimal>> insertRecord2(req2.get(),useFallBack){..}

public Observable<Optional<JRecord>> getJRecord(req3.getAccountId(),req4.getId(),useFallBack){..}

public Observable<Optional<BigDecimal>> getTaxRate(req3.getAccountId(),useFallBack){..}

public Observable<Optional<Currency>> getCurrencyByCode(req3.getCurrencyCode(), useFallBack){..}
```

Is there any chance that while using RxJava at service layer, Spring is not supporting the transaction as because the the repository call will happen when method return from service layer after observable subscribed?

Waiting for reply.

Thanks

Comment: Reactive transaction suppor thas been added in Spriung 5.2 and only (afaik) for Project Reactor. Earlier versions don't have transaction support. So in  your case no support for reactive transactions.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Does Spring 5.2 supports RxJava Observable?

Comment: Yes, but not for transactional support afaik.

Comment: function needs to return Publisher to get the support
[reactive-transactions-with-spring](https://spring.io/blog/2019/05/16/reactive-transactions-with-spring)